# Entity Framework async call blocking UI thread

Tags: wpf, mvvm, async-await, entity-framework-6, mvvm-light

I have been slowly trying to convert my code from using action delegates to the new Tasks in my WPF application. I like the fact that an await operation can run in the same method, greatly reducing the number of methods I need, enhancing readability, and reducing maintenance. That being said, I am having a problem with my code when calling EF6 async methods. They all seem to run synchronously and are blocking my UI thread. I use the following technologies/frameworks in my code:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- WPF
- MVVM Light 5.2
- Generic Unit Of Work/Repository Framework v3.3.5
  https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/
- Entity Framework 6.1.1
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

As an example, I have a LogInViewModel, with a command that executes after a button is clicked on my WPF application. Here is the command as initialized in the constructor:

```
LogInCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteLogInCommand());
```

Here is the command body:

```
private async void ExecuteLogInCommand()
{
     // Some code to validate user input

     var user = await _userService.LogIn(username, password);

     // Some code to confirm log in
}
```

The user service uses a generic repository object that is created using MVVM Light's SimpleIoC container. The LogIn method looks like this:

```
public async Task<User> LogIn(string username, string password)
{
    User user = await _repository.FindUser(username);

    if (user != null && user.IsActive)
    {
        // Some code to verify passwords
        return user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

And my repository code to log in:

```
public static async Task<User> FindUser(this IRepositoryAsync<User> repository, string username)
{
    return await repository.Queryable().Where(u => u.Username == username).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

The SingleOrDefaultAsync() call is Entity Framework's async call. This code is blocking my UI thread. I have read multiple articles from Stephen Cleary and others about async await and proper use. I have tried using ConfigureAwait(false) all the way down, with no luck. I have made my RelayCommand call use the async await keywords with no luck. I have analyzed the code and the line that takes the longest to return is the SingleOrDefaultAsync() line. Everything else happens almost instantaneously. I have the same problem when making other async calls to the DB in my code. The only thing that fixes it right away is the following:

```
User user = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    return _userService.LogIn(Username, p.Password);
});
```

But I understand this should not be necessary since the call I am making to the database is IO bound and not CPU bound. So, what is wrong with my application and why is it blocking my UI thread?

Comment: What exactly is `.Queryable()` on the repository class? On what are you calling it? Does `IRepositoryAsync<User>` inherit from other interfaces and what exactly is its implementation

Comment: @Tseng Queriable() just returns the underlying User dbset, to which you can apply any Entity Framework method call. IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> is the interface provided by the Generic Repository/UnitOfWork framework. It also provides an EF6 implementation. I didn't add any of the code in it the because it's extensive. I provided the link above, so you can take a look at it if you like. Thanks!

Comment: Your pattern looks fine to me, some recommendations: Shorten the syntax at the generation to `new RelayCommand`; you do not need the `() =>` part. Also, you may remove in your repository code the `async` and the `await` keyword, if you do not modify the returned object. With this small change you will save the generation of an in this case unnecessary Task object. For your `async` problem: you could try to use the `Select` Method on the  `IRepositoryAsync<>`, instead of `Queryable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RelayCommand` is not async.

```
LogInCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteLogInCommand());
```

Because there is no `async`/`await` your `ExecuteLogInCommand` will be called synchronously.

You got to change it to

```
LogInCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await ExecuteLogInCommand());
```

so that the `RelayCommand` is called async too.

Comment: That would only generate another state machine with no practical effect.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: But if `ExecuteLogInCommand` is called without `await` or chained with `.ContinueWith()` it will automatically run synchronously, no matter if the calls below are async or not. When using async/await you have to use async all the way down

Comment: @Tseng I tried making the command call async with the async/await keywords. It still blocks.

Comment: @Tseng, the only thing the `async` modifier does is generating a state machine. The code could just be `LogInCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteLogInCommand);` and it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LogIn` and `FindUser` (which, [according to the guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh873175), should be called `LogInAsync` and `FindUserAsync`) which are not supposed to work with the UI should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all awaits.

However all calls are synchronous until something really asynchronous is called. I suppose that would be `SingleOrDefaultAsync`.

If wrapping it in `Task.Run` makes such a difference, then, for some reason, `SingleOrDefaultAsync` must be running synchronously.

Comment: Paulo Morgado thanks for your reply. I tried using ConfigureAwait(false) all the way down, with no luck. What do you mean by "which are not supposed to work with the UI"? Thanks!

Comment: Any method that is not supposed to work with the UI (meant to work independently of the synchronization context) should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on every `await`.